# How to create an active rule in Oracle in order to restrict database operations during given time period?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Need to add an active rule to restrict data update in Oracle database.

Comment: In the whole database or just in a schema?

Comment: Schema only no change is done for the database.

Comment: How many tables do you have in the Schema?

Comment: 15 tables are there.

Comment: You can create VPD rules  or  create views on the table and use instead of triggers but that will cost performance, Exactly what actions you don't want to permit on the table?